# Como inserir um caractere no meio da frase

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou implementando uma função que verifica se dentro de uma palavra há duas letras iguais seguidas, e, em caso positivo, acrescente um 'x' entre as duas letras para separá-las.

Exemplo:

- Entrada: `pizza`
- Saída: `pizxza`

```
def checagem_letras(self):
    i = 0
    for letra in self.__frase:
        if self.__frase[i] == self.__frase[i+1]:
            ?????????
```

Não sei qual metódo implementar para fazer o código funcionar.

Comment: Diovana Valim, haverão casos onde a entrada pode ser mais de duas letras repetidas? Exemplo: 'Pizzza', 'Carburadorrrrrrrr'

Comment: Complementando o comentário do @AugustoVasques, eu entendi que se a string for `'aaa'`, o resultado deve ser `'axaxa'` (um "x" inserido entre cada ocorrência de duas repetições da mesma letra), inclusive respondi com códigos que fazem isso...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode resolver o seu problema de uma maneira bastante "pythônica" usando um [gerador](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generators) combinado com uma [máquina de estados](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A1quina_de_estados_finita), veja só:

```
def substituir(string):
  ultimo = None
  for atual in string:
    if atual == ultimo:
      yield 'x'
    yield atual
    ultimo = atual

s = "pizza carro passaro"
print(''.join(substituir(s)))
```

Saída:

```
pizxza carxro pasxsaro
```

Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/NoisyDarkblueRoot)

Answer (score 4):

Uma solução é ir percorrendo os caracteres da string, e só adicionar o "x" se o caractere seguinte for igual ao atual:

```
class Test:

  def __init__(self, frase):
    self.__frase = frase;

  def checagem_letras(self):
    result = ''
    for i, letra in enumerate(self.__frase):
        result += letra
        if i < len(self.__frase) - 1 and letra == self.__frase[i + 1]:
            result += 'x'
    return result

print(Test("pizza").checagem_letras()) # pizxza
print(Test("pizzaiollo").checagem_letras()) # pizxzaiolxlo
print(Test("aaa bbbb").checagem_letras()) # axaxa bxbxbxb
```

Eu uso [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) para percorrer os caracteres da string, e ao mesmo tempo já tenho o respectivo índice. Assim eu consigo verificar o caractere seguinte - tomando o devido cuidado de verificar se não estou no último caractere (a condição `i < len(self.__frase) - 1`), pois neste caso eu não posso verificar o caractere seguinte (caso contrário tentarei acessar um índice que não existe e ocorrerá um [`IndexError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#IndexError)).

Se o caractere seguinte for igual ao atual, eu adiciono o "x". No final eu retorno a string alterada.

O detalhe é que eu precisei construir outra string, já que strings são imutáveis em Python (veja a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#textseq)), então não é possível alterar os índices de uma string já existente. Ou seja, esse código:

```
s = 'abc'
s[1] = 'x'
```

Causa um [`TypeError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#TypeError) ([veja](https://ideone.com/UQ2XK7)), pois eu tentei alterar um índice da string. Por isso o único jeito de fazer o que você quer é criar outra string.

Vale notar também que no caso de 3 repetições (`aaa`) eu entendi que o resultado deve ser um "x" inserido entre cada ocorrência de duas letras repetidas, e portanto o resultado deve ser `axaxa` (não ficou claro se esse caso acontece, nem o que deve acontecer caso aconteça).

---

Não ficou claro se o método deve retornar a string alterada ou apenas modificar a frase atual. Se quer somente modificar a frase atual, faça:

```
def checagem_letras(self):
    result = ''
    for i, letra in enumerate(self.__frase):
        result += letra
        if i < len(self.__frase) - 1 and letra == self.__frase[i + 1]:
            result += 'x'
    # modifico a frase em vez de retornar
    self.__frase = result
```

---

Além disso, o algoritmo acima insere o "x" para qualquer caractere que se repete (não somente letras). Mas se quiser se restringir a letras, pode alterar a condição do `if`. Por exemplo:

```
if i < len(self.__frase) - 1 and letra.isalpha() and letra == self.__frase[i + 1]:
```

Eu usei [`isalpha()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha), que verifica se é uma letra (assim, outros caracteres serão ignorados, mesmo se estiverem repetidos). Mude a condição para o que você precisar.

---

Outra forma de fazer - um pouco mais complicada, e admito que para este caso é um certo "exagero", já que a solução acima é bem mais simples - é usar [expressões regulares (regex)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

```
import re

class Test:

  def __init__(self, frase):
    self.__frase = frase;

  def checagem_letras(self):
    return re.sub(r'([a-zA-Z])(?=\1)', r'\1x', self.__frase)

print(Test("pizza").checagem_letras()) # pizxza
print(Test("pizzaiollo").checagem_letras()) # pizxzaiolxlo
print(Test("aaa bbbb").checagem_letras()) # axaxa bxbxbxb
```

A regex usa a [classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[a-zA-Z]`, que pega uma letra de `a` a `z` (minúscula ou maiúscula) e como está entre parênteses, isso forma um [grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

Depois eu uso um [*lookahead*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (o trecho entre `(?=` e `)`), que verifica se algo existe à frente. E esse algo é `\1`, que é uma [*backreference*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) e significa "a mesma coisa que foi capturada pelo grupo de captura 1". No caso, o grupo 1 é o primeiro par de parênteses, que é o que contém a letra de `a` a `z`. Ou seja, a regex verifica se tem uma letra repetida.

Em seguida, na substituição eu uso `\1x`, ou seja, a letra que a regex detectou que se repete (a *backreference* `\1`), seguida de um "x".

Neste caso estou sendo bem restrito e só insiro o "x" quando for uma letra repetida. Mas se quiser ser mais genérico como a primeira opção acima e considerar qualquer caractere (não apenas letras), pode trocar a classe de caracteres por um ponto:

```
def checagem_letras(self):
    return re.sub(r'(.)(?=\1)', r'\1x', self.__frase)
```

Pois em regex, o ponto corresponde a [qualquer caractere (exceto quebras de linha)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html).

Comment: acho que vale comentar que a abordagem tem que ser essa por que strings são imutáveis em Python - então sempre será necessário construir uma outra string, como é feito na variável "result" aqui. Não há como só inserir a letra direto na string que já está no atributo .__frase

Comment: @jsbueno Bem lembrado, atualizei a resposta, obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar usar a o método [sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) do módulo [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) que fornece operações de correspondência de expressões regulares.

```
re.sub( padrão , repl , sequência , contagem = 0 , sinalizadores = 0 )
```

`sub()` retorna uma string obtida substituindo as ocorrências do padrão na seqüência pela substituição repl . Se o padrão não for encontrado, a sequência será retornada inalterada.

```
import re

frase = 'Zicco, hojje tem pizza.'

#São gerados dois grupos de captura `[r'\w\w',r'\w']`->`[r'\1',r'\2']` no caso ele substitui 
#a ocorrência dobrando segundo grupo de captura e inserindo x entre `\2x\2` 
frase_pocessada = re.sub(r'((\w)\2+)',r'\2x\2',frase)

print(frase_pocessada)
```

Código no Repl.it: https://repl.it/repls/DarkorchidEverlastingScript

Comment: Só um detalhe, se a string for `'aaa'`, eu entendi que o resultado deve ser `axaxa` (e na [minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/437520/112052) tem uma regex que faz isso). Mas como não ficou claro se esse caso acontece, a sua regex já resolve os casos de apenas duas letras repetidas :-)

Comment: @hkotsubo até perguntei para o AP se haverão casos diferenciados de entrada. Pois a minha regex trata toda repetição como se fossem sempre uma dupla.